# checkout a product VAT ValidationExtensionS Service Provider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, custom-validators

I am facing an issue with custom validation while checkout a product VAT Validation.

But i am running with this error:

> Class 'App\Providers\ValidationExtensionS Service Provider' not found.

Can any one able to help me how to fix this issue.

I had attached my valadatorextended.php file over here :

```
namespace App\Services;
use App\Services\ValidatorExtended;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as IlluminateValidator;
class ValidatorExtended extends IlluminateValidator {
private $_custom_messages = array(
   "vat" => "The :attribute is not a valid VAT.",
   //place for more customized messages
);
public function __construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
parent::__construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );

 $this->_set_custom_stuff();
}

protected function _set_custom_stuff() {
   //setup our custom error messages
   $this->setCustomMessages( $this->_custom_messages );
}

protected function validateVat( $attribute, $value ) {
   // You can extend your RegEx with other Countries, if you like

   return (bool) preg_match( "/((DK|FI|HU|LU|MT|SI)(-)?\d{8})|((BE|EE|DE|EL|LT|PT)(-)?\d{9})|((PL|SK)(-)?\d{10})|((IT|LV)(-)?\d{11})|((LT|SE)(-)?\d{12})|(AT(-)?U\d{8})|(CY(-)?\d{8}[A-Z])|(CZ(-)?\d{8,10})|(FR(-)?[\dA-HJ-NP-Z]{2}\d{9})|(IE(-)?\d[A-Z\d]\d{5}[A-Z])|(NL(-)?\d{9}B\d{2})|(ES(-)?[A-Z\d]\d{7}[A-Z\d])/", $value );
  }

   //place for more protected functions for other custom validations

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've messed up your `Use` statement somewhere. If your trying to use the `ValidatorExtended` class, your `use` statement should look like:

```
use App\Services\ValidatorExtended;
```

Looking at it, the code you are providing doesn't seem to fit the error given.

Comment: Yes i trying to built from this :
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-form-validation-for-vat?page=1
Can you help me out how to specify the route .

Comment: For ex : I have the route like this for other functionalities :
Route::get('bank', array('as' => 'bank','uses' => 'Frontend\CartController@paymentBank'));

Can you let me know how can i specify route for custom validation.